# Mocking an ES6 class function with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I have a question about how can I mock an ES6 class instance using Jest which is used by the method I actually want to test.
My real case is trying to test a Redux async action creator that make a request and dispatch some action depending on the request result.

This is a simplified example of the use case :

```
// communication.js
// An exported ES6 class module with proxy to the request library.
import post from './post';
export default class communication {

    getData(data, success, error) {
        const res = post(data);
        if(res) {
            success();
        } else {
            error();
        }
    }
}

// communicatorAssist.js
// A redux async function using communication.js
import communication from './communication';
// ...

export function retrieveData() {
    return dispatch => {
        const data = { name: 'michel'};
        communication.getData(data,
            (res) => dispatch(successAction(res)),
            (res) => dispatch(errorAction(res));
    }
}

// communicatorAssist.test.js testing the communicatorAssist
import { retrieveData } from 'communicatorAssist';

// communication.getData should call success callback
// for this test.
it('Should call the success callback', () => {
    retrieveData();
    // Assert that mocked redux store contains actions
});

// communication.getData should call error callback
// for this test.
it('Should call the error callback', () => {
    retrieveData();
    // Assert that mocked redux store contains actions
});
```

What I want is mocking the communication class in the test and change the behaviour of the `getData()` function in each test to call `success` and `error` callbacks without any call to post method.

I only success to mock the `getData()` function for the whole test file with this snippet at the top of it :

```
import communication from '../communication'
jest.mock('../communication', () => (() => ({
    getData: (success, error) => success()
})));
```

but I can't switch between implementation in different test case.

I figure that something using `.mockImplementation()` could do the stuff but I can't make this work in my case (I saw examples using it for module exporting functions but not for classes ).

Does anyone have an idea ?

**Edit** :

I forgot a part in the code exemple : the communication class instance creation which I think is the "problem" for mocking it :

```
const com = new communication();
```

If `com` is instanciated at a global level in the communicatorAssist.js file : it fail with *communication.getData is not a function* error.

But if I set the instanciation inside the `retrieveData()` function, Andreas Köberle snippet work's fine :

```
import communication from '../communication'
jest.mock('../communication', () => jest.fn());

communication.mockImplementation(
  () => ({
    getData: (success, error) => success()
  })
)
```

(`jest.mock()` factory parameter need to return a function not directly `jest.fn`)

I don't know why it's not working using a file global scope instance.

Answer (score 17):

You need to mock the module with `jest.fn()` then you can import it and change the behaviour of it using [`mockImplementation`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn):

```
import communication from '../communication'
jest.mock('../communication', jest.fn());

communication.mockImplementation(
  () => ({
    getData: (success, error) => success()
  })
)
```

Comment: I've edited the question with your answer which works great in case the communication class is instanciated in the retrieveData function.

Comment: what if the result of getData has to vary across tests in this test file?

Comment: @Marc then you create various different communication mocks each having their own mocked getData function.

Comment: 2nd line produces following error ```The second argument of `jest.mock` must be an inline function```